# Compare two .class file with hash value

Tags: java, hash, compiler-construction

I find that compilers can make different .class files with the same .java source files. I just tried to compile .java files with Ant and Eclipse and the results' file sizes are different, that makes the hash values of those files don't match.

With Ant, I found that there are some empty anonymous inner classes have been generated. So, how can I match the .class files from different compilers via hash value or anything quick?

Note: If I generate the .class file to .java back, the hash values match. Is this the only way?

Comment: Why do you need to compare the class files? Different compiler settings (e.g., optimization levels, debug info, etc.) can change the .class file, making matching difficult... what specifically are you trying to archive by comparing the class files?

Comment: I want a quick way to detect file reuse. For analyzing.

Answer (score 2):

> So, how can I match the .class files from different compilers via hash value or anything quick?

In a nutshell, I don't think there's an easy way. Different compilers could well produce different bytecodes from the same source code.

It might be worth studying the literature though. A quick Google search has found this:

> [A Plagiarism Detection Technique for Java Program Using Bytecode Analysis](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224351648_A_Plagiarism_Detection_Technique_for_Java_Program_Using_Bytecode_Analysis)
>
> Jeong-Hoon Ji, Gyun Woo, Hwan-Gue Cho
>
> ABSTRACT Most plagiarism detection systems evaluate the similarity of source codes and detect plagiarized program pairs. If we use the source codes in plagiarism detection, the source code security can be a significant problem. Plagiarism detection based on target code can be used for protecting the security of source codes. In this paper, we propose anew plagiarism detection technique for Java programs using bytecodes without referring their source codes. The plagiarism detection procedure using bytecode consists of two major steps. First, we generate the token sequences from the Java class file by analyzing the code area of methods. Then, we evaluate the similarity between token sequences using the adaptive local alignment. According to the experimental results, we can find the distributions of similarities of the source codes and that of bytecodes are very similar. Also, the correlation between the similarities of source code pairs and those of bytecode pairs is high enough for typical test data. The plagiarism detection system using bytecode can be used as a preliminary verifying tool before detecting the plagiarism by source code comparison.

There's also [Deducing Similarities in Java Sources from Bytecodes](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/library/proceedings/usenix98/full_papers/baker/baker.pdf), but it's extremely dated in Java terms (1998). Might still be a worthwhile source of ideas though.

I am sure there is more literature. This is what I could find in two minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I actually want to build code similarity detection, however I want to quick detect library files similarity using hash value first so it can be excluded in further detection. Appreciate the link.

Comment: @Zyoo: I don't think hashing is the right tool for detecting similarity, unless you come up with some locality-sensitive hashing scheme (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing).